# How to spawn in Objects in unity2d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a script for spawning "enemies" above the player for them to dodge.  I am having a bit of trouble because I am new at c#, even though it seems like it should be easy.  Any help would be greatly apricated!

Comment: So there's a bit involve in doing that.   [**Kailokk 's** fine answer below should set you on your way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70407976/585968) but it's highly recommended to either check out the tons of tutorials on YouTube or at least the Unity Learn site.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You would use [Object.Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html)

You can create a [Prefab](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html) of the monster you want to spawn.

It would look something like:

```cs
private void MonsterSpawner(Vector2 spawnLocation)
{
    Instantiate(prefab, spawnLocation);
}
```